# Real time display command line message on browser

Tags: python, django

I have ajax call on client side to ask server side call the subprocess to execute a matlab program.Now in my server side is doing this:

```
def meta2db(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):

        cur_status = status.objects.all()
        Dataset = cur_status[0].Dataset
        print(Dataset)

        is_multiclass = request.POST.get('multiclass', False)
        if(is_multiclass != 'on'):
            is_multiclass = 'false'

        require_mapper = request.POST.get('require_mapper', False)

        if(require_mapper == 'on'):
            mapper = request.POST.get('cls_mapper_pth', False)
        else:
            require_mapper= 'false'
            mapper = 'none'


        require_aspect_ratio = request.POST.get('require_aspect_ratio', False)
        if(require_aspect_ratio == 'on'):
            aspect_ratio = request.POST.get('aspect_ratio', False)
        else:
            require_aspect_ratio = 'false'
            aspect_ratio ='none'



        run_octave(Dataset,is_multiclass,require_mapper,mapper,require_aspect_ratio,aspect_ratio)


    return render(request, 'meta2db.html')

def run_octave(dataset,is_multiclass,require_mapper,mapper,require_aspect_ratio,aspect_ratio):

    origWD = os.getcwd()
    args = ["octave", "dbEval.m",dataset,is_multiclass,require_mapper,\
    mapper,require_aspect_ratio,aspect_ratio]

    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(sys.path[0]), "../scripts/"))
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #print(os.listdir("../scripts/results/chruch_street/"))

    time.sleep(10)
    if process.poll() is None:
        process.kill()
    else:
        print(p.communicate())
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line)
    os.chdir(origWD)
```

Now the problem is that I want to return the command line message which is

```
for line in process.stdout:
            print(line)
```

to client side and real time show the message to the brower.

what strategy should i take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out `channels` which specifically designed for Django to solve this problem.

```
from channel import Group 

Group('octave').send({'text': line})
```

And initialise websocket in frontend to receive this messages.

Comment: can you explain it more detail!?

Comment: Sure.. But if you follow the Getting started docs. Comes up with specific problem I can happy to assist you .

Comment: just read. curious this is probably not the one im looking for becuase this for the multiuser. in my case i just want the backend keep the front-end know what part of exec this doing it right now.

Comment: Define user, Assign unique key to each user and publish your message to that user. Or leave it as it is. Every `/` url receive your message. which part is hard

Comment: this so difficult..

Comment: Okay tell me where in the doc your are doing ?

Comment: i follow the example and do a small project based on https://realpython.com/blog/python/getting-started-with-django-channels/
but i cant reproduce it in my case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147041/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-pwan).